# determine how many AWS instances are in a zone

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I need to find out how many AWS instances we have running in each AWS region. So for instance I would have to find out how many are running in us-east-1 for example. I came up with this one liner, that I think will do the trick.

```
 aws ec2 describe-instances --profile=company-nonprod |grep ami-*|uniq |wc -l
147
```

I'm just not sure how accurate and reflective of reality that would be. Can I get some opinions on the best way to do it? Also I need to know how many are running vs non-running (i.e. shutdown or terminated instances don't matter).

Comment: `zone` or `region`? `us-east-1` is a region. In your one liner, there is no reference to `us-east-1`

Comment: sorry I meant region. I've updated the question to reflect that. Thanks

Comment: and the profile supplies the region information to the command. For example: `λ aws configure --profile=company-dlab
AWS Access Key ID [********************]:
AWS Secret Access Key [********************]:
Default region name [us-east-1]:
Default output format [text]:`

Answer (score 3):

`ami-` can appear in a tag name/value. Not a reliable way. try counting the instances by their id for accurate results.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --profile=company-nonprod --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId]' --output text | wc -l
```

If Python and Boto3 are installed:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import boto3.session
import sys

sess = boto3.session.Session(profile_name=sys.argv[1])
ec2 = sess.resource('ec2')
print len(list(ec2.instances.all()))
```

Save it as `count.py` and make it an executable. Then call:

```
count.py company-nonprod
```

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't get an accurate count from that line. I got back a result of 1, which isn't right. ` aws ec2 describe-instances --profile=company-nonprod --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId]' --output text | wc -l
1`. And I can see 83 running instances in that region. Also I need to know how many are running vs not running. I'll update the question to reflect that need.

Comment: I need to determine this programatically so that I can get the number of instances running in all our regions from all our accounts.

Comment: @bluethundr see my update. You need Python and Boto3 for this example. Without knowing your dev environment, it is difficult to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple to display the **Availability Zone**, which incorporates the region:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[0].[InstanceId,Placement.AvailabilityZone]' --output text

i-3da618a2  ap-southeast-2b
i-5d261640  ap-southeast-2a
i-9c57c651  ap-southeast-2a
```

However, there's an important thing to realise... When making an API call to AWS, **you must specify the region as part of the call**. Therefore, only instances **in that region** will be returned. You need to repeat the process for every region.

Here's a python script that will go through all regions, listing instances, tags and state:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import boto.ec2

for region in [r for r in boto.ec2.regions() if r.name not in ['cn-north-1', 'us-gov-west-1']]:
  conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region(region.name)
  reservations = conn.get_all_instances()
  for r in reservations:
    for i in r.instances:
      print region.name, i.id, i.tags, i.state
```

Output looks like this:

```
us-east-1 i-581c7164 {u'Name': u'US-East'} stopped
```

Answer (score 0):

@John is right but you can still pipe those information from bash directly and no need (at this stage) for another sdk

```
aws ec2 describe-regions --output text |\
cut -f 3 | \
xargs -I {} aws ec2 describe-instances \
    --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[Placement.AvailabilityZone, State.Name, InstanceId]' \
    --output text \
    --region {}
```

The first part of the command will return all the available regions so it will pass the region to the second part of the command, and it will correctly run against all region and you dont need to hardcode anything

It will list all your instances  for each region and their status (if running or not)